# Nozzle inlet and outlet diameter for a shell and tube heat exchanger

Tags: chemical-engineering, heat-exchanger

Hi I have designed a shell and tube heat exchanger to cool octane and water. I have all the dimensions but I was unsure which equation to use to calculate the diameter for the inlet and outlet nozzles. Does anyone know an equation I could use?

Comment: I expect TEMA could help with that ; but likely some cost .

Comment: If you designed the heat exchanger and "have all the dimensions", shouldn't the inlet and outlet dimension be trivial to calculate?